# AngularDart: ng-switch in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, dart, angular-dart

Can someone please explain to me why the following code is working in angular but not angularDart..?

```
<div ng-repeat='number in [1,2,3]' ng-switch on='number'>
  <div ng-switch-when='2'>This is numer two!</div>
</div>
```

Thanks!

Comment: what exactly is not working? do you have any errors?

Comment: @EliranMalka In angular its showing the div once, as expected. But in angular-dart i get nothing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I seems to me, the [API for AngularDart](https://docs.angulardart.org/#angular/angular.NgSwitchWhen@id_ngSwitch) doesn't have the `on` attribute while the [Angular API](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSwitch) leaves the programmer the choice between using `ng-switch on='...'` or `ng-switch='...'`.

So for both, Angular and AngularDart, the following might work:

```
<div ng-repeat='number in [1,2,3]' ng-switch='number'>
  <div ng-switch-when='2'>This is numer two!</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Oh, can't believe i missed that one. Thanks a lot!